# javascript - Exception was thrown in jquery ajax - IE11 but not Chrome - how to locate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for suggestions on how to debug this:

Exception was thrown at line 2, column 10440 in http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError

Happens in IE11 but not Chrome.  No known functional issues, just annoying and faintly worrisome that it might indicate something more serious.

Does not show in IE's F12 console.

Add this to webconfig, no change:

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

I put try/catch around the areas in the JS where it might be happening, haven't been able to trap it.

Unfortunately, the code is very complex, so I'm unable to upload it.

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the un-minified version available for jQuery, are you able to see the line of code which is throwing the SyntaxError?

Comment: Can you post the part of your code that is using jQuery and causing the error?

Comment: @kaz, unfortunately, there are 9000 lines of js and even the likely possibilities are spread out;  I wouldn't know which area to post.

Comment: @Anthony:  I'll try an unminified version.   I've slightly better isolated when it happens within the processing cycle;  if I can see the jq code that might help.